# VB6 to VB.net conversion

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

**Exact duplicate: [Best strategy for moving applications from VB6 to VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683918/best-strategy-for-moving-from-vb6-to-net)

 Exact duplicate: [Conversion tool comparisons for VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718780/conversion-tool-comparisons-for-visual-basic-6-0)**

can any one please tell the tool which converts vb6 to vb.net

thanks 
dagg

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of several other questions on VB6 migration tools. in my opinion, for whatever that's worth, the answers are better on those other questions too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conversion tool comparisons for visual basic 6.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718780/conversion-tool-comparisons-for-visual-basic-6-0)

Comment: I'm astonished by the number of VB6 migrations that appear to still be pending (checked the "Viewed" count on this question!).  Note that there are no good answers here, and no updates since December '09.  FWIW, the "upgrade tool" mentioned is no longer available with modern versions of Visual Studio.  I suspect it is very hard to get the older versions; certainly MS doesn't offer them any more.

Comment: MS doesn’t offer it anymore but the tool is still available. The company that develop this tool is now called Mobilize.Net. The tools is not called Upgrade Wizard anymore it is now called Visual Basic Upgrade Companion (VBUC). I think there was an MSDN trial or it can be downloaded from their WebSite. MS still works with them you can see an Legacy VB6 to Azure demo at https://github.com/microsoft/TailwindTraders-PointOfSale and a lot of material at https://github.com/MobilizeNet/VbMigration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is one that comes with vb.net. When you open a .vbp vb6 project, it asks if you would like to automatically convert it to vb.net. It does a pretty good job, exclusive of third party add-ons.

Comment: The built-in migration wizard does a **terrible** job: it adds hundreds of "TODO" comments to mark things you will have to fix manually. There are third party tools that do a better job. There's good discussion in the other VB migration questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb6-migration

Comment: @MarkJ The built-in tool has a huge advantage: it's free. The third-party tools are very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try Visual Basic Upgrade Companion. 
It generates `VB .NET` and `C#` and maps `COM` components to Framework components.

[pr_vb_companion](http://www.artinsoft.com/pr_vbcompanion.aspx)

Comment: There's some more discussion of this Artinsoft tool, it's competitor from Francesco Balena, and the other issues involved in the other VB6 migration questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb6-migration

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Corp just published a world-wide case study based on the successful VB6 migration project:

http://www.microsoft.com/casestudies/Case_Study_Detail.aspx?casestudyid=4000006181

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Visual Studio has a built-in VB6 -> VB .NET project and source conversion component built in. I haven't used it for a while, last time I did a conversion was with Visual Studio 2005. It was a little tricky, and there was still some manual clean up involved to get things working just right. I don't know what the VS2008 system is like.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly not a trivial matter.

DotNetRocks recently did a show on this, which you will find here - Francesco Balena on VB to .NET Migration - http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=491

This will introduce you to some of the issues, and indeed, a tool to do a conversion.

Comment: There's some more discussion of Francesco Balena's tool, and it's competitor from Artinsoft, and the other issues involved in the other VB6 migration questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb6-migration