# Convert project from vb6 to vb.net Visual Studio 2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, vb6, vb6-migration

I want to convert my old vb6 project to a vb.Net solution, when I open do: `File->Open->Convert` this is what I get:

[image]

And I can't find a way to show the available converters...

I have try:

- Installing framework 1.0 since I read somewhere that it's needed
- Tried to install framework 2.0 but it's says "I have it" but it's not showing in the uninstall programs list
- Tried to install framework 3.0, same as before.
- I even try to add the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.UpgradeWizard.dll` via `regasm` but I can't open a console command in VS2008, only in VS2010 and I have read that VS2010 can't handle the conversion from vb6 to vb.net, it has to pass over VS2008 first.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JimmyPena I don't think so, I just checked it in other browsers, try refreshing the page...

Comment: @JimmyPena it's ok, same here

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Strategy for moving from VB6 to .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683918/best-strategy-for-moving-from-vb6-to-net)

Comment: @C-PoundGuru This question is about the converter not working in VS2008 on one user's computer. It is absolutely **not** a duplicate of questions about which is the best conversion strategy.

Comment: @C-PoundGuru as you can see in the full description of the question, I can't choose a best strategy since **I can't even convert for the first time...**

Comment: @LuisSánchez: You're looking for a silver bullet (or an easy button).  There really isn't one.  You gotta do the work.

Comment: My guess is that VS2010 has uninstalled it? Try completely uninstalling VS2010 and re-installing VS2008. However even if you get this working I doubt it will convert it for you in a meaningful way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the solution was to install Visual Studio 2005, then the converters were available:

I suppose I needed Framework 1.0.

[image: Image showing the upgrade wizard]

It's not perfect, it has some errors, but its a step forward for a complete solution.

Of course I've found some other 3rd party conversion programs, but they are expensive:

- [ArtInSoft](http://www.artinsoft.com/)
- [Visualwebgui](http://www.visualwebgui.com/)

Hope it helps someone else!

Comment: The conversion wizard is in 2008, too. That's the last version it was provided with.

Answer (score 0):

No clue what that Convert dialog is for--there's nothing in the help on it.

According to this [Forum Post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbinterop/thread/8709a99b-e124-453e-bcf3-46d03deadc64), you can open the vbp in Visual Studio and it should ask to convert the project (no option to open a .vbp file in VS 2010).  However, even if it still did that in VS 2010, it's a tremendously bad idea.

See also [this post](http://visualbasic.about.com/b/2011/01/24/converting-vb6-to-vb-net.htm) on converting VB6 to VB.NET.

Also, check these duplicated SO questions:

- [VB6 to VB.NET Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678064/vb6-to-vb-net-conversion)
- [How to Switch a Large App From Vb6 to VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395/how-to-switch-a-large-app-from-vb6-to-vb-net)
- [Best Strategy for Moving from VB6 to .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683918/best-strategy-for-moving-from-vb6-to-net)

<strike>**Edit:**
According to [this MSDN Page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317885#appliesto), the conversion wizard only goes up to Visual Studio 2005</strike>

**Edit Edit:** Per MarkJ's comment, Visual Studio 2008 [includes the upgrade wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47s4twtx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). It's gone in VS 2010.

Comment: Yes, i've seen all those posts, including this one which gives you the best step to step process http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8004/On-Migrating-a-VB-Project-to-VB-NET now the problem is that i can't find a way to show those converters

Comment: @LuisSánchez: The most likely reason you can't see the converters is that Microsoft doesn't support VB6 to VB.NET conversion anymore.  Perhaps an older version of Visual Studio (2003) would do it.  Even if you can click the magic button, you will still have a huge mess on your hands--perhaps even bigger than just doing the work and writing the code.  That's what I've had to do.

Comment: Visual Studio 2008 [includes the upgrade wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47s4twtx(v=vs.90).aspx). It was removed in VS 2010. The MSDN page you linked says the tool existed in VS2005. It **does not** say it was removed in any version.

Comment: @MarkJ: Thanks for pointing that out--didn't read more after finding the first article.