# Convert VB 6.0 to latest version of VB

Tags: vb.net

sorry for asking this, but I'm really newbie to this. I just receive a code from my boss and it is a code with VB 6.0 version, he then ask me to convert into the latest version of VB. Now I get confused because when I google I found out that the latest version is VB 6.0 . So I get confused now.

Can anyone correct me if I'm wrong and if theres any latest version,how can i convert it? Is there any converter tools like [developerfussion](http://www.developerfusion.com)? TQ

Comment: I thought the codes are 'backward compatible'? The answer I can give you is that you're confused with your boss requirement, give him a call and clarify with him, that's what you need.

Comment: @Sky thanks, just to confirm. The latest version of Vb is 6.0 right?

Comment: Yes it is the latest Visual Basic, its final release was in 1998. Unless you're talking about VB 6.0 to VB.net

Comment: @Sky Means the code older than VB 6.0 is backward compatible? sorry I need to clarify a few things before I give him a call.

Comment: VB.net which some people refers as VB 7.0 and above are not backwards compatible. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET

Comment: Microsoft no longer uses the term "VB.NET" - they just call it "Visual Basic" now, so there's understandable confusion.  Your boss is probably talking about converting VB6 code to the latest "VB.NET" code (although Microsoft doesn't call it that).

Comment: If your boss do mean VB.net then this thread might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678064/vb6-to-vb-net-conversion

Comment: @Sky oh okay then he might be asking me to convert to the latest VB.NET as Dave said. So is there any way i can do the conversion? or I need to restructure the whole codes?

Comment: @DaveDoknjas thanks, So is there any way i can do the conversion? or I need to restructure the whole codes?

Comment: There are migration tools. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678064/vb6-to-vb-net-conversion

However it is not 100% successful. But converting vb6 to vb.net isn't that difficult too as the codes are very similar.

Comment: Get a copy of Visual Studio 2008 - it was the last one with the upgrade wizard.  It's not perfect, but I've used it myself to convert a few large projects.  Also, an old book from Microsoft called "Upgrading Visual Basic 6.0 to Visual Basic.NET" is a useful reference.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas Im using VS express 2013. IS it possible to do the same thing?

Comment: @Sky do you know what version of VB that support framework 4.0?

Comment: 2010 and above. (VB 10.0)

Answer (score 3):

I don't recommend a direct translation. VB 6.0 was the last release for the classic visual basic. After that it became in VB.net, which is not the same, is a 100% object oriented programming language but, you could be able to convert it by hand. Since VB.net is OOP and VB 6 is not you can transcript from VB 6.0 to VB.net using the procedural way, loosing all of the OOP advantages. The other thing you can do is re-write the program from scratch to VB.net, which is going to take a while but it will worth it. The latest version for Visual Studio is 2013.

Comment: I have a blog with ebooks and documentation about programming, networkin and OS, which includes VB.net, C#, C++, Java... Maybe you can find a useful tutorial or book http://computertechnologydocumentation.blogspot.com/p/blog-page_288.html

Answer (score 0):

Your boss may sugest a convertion from visual basic 6 to vb.net. You have several tools to do that. You can use the free visual studio 2008 Express (open and convert the code), or you can try the mobilize vb upgrade tool (free until 10.000 lines of code).
https://www.mobilize.net/solution/msdn

This limit of loc is quite small, exclude the comments but includes all the code and the design code.

You have lots of help here using the
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb6-migration