# msstdfmt.dll 1.0.0 missing error

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, vb6

I was given some old code today that needs to be converted up.  I am running win7 64, have VS10,11,12 Ultimate on my machine and just downloaded and installed VS2008 Express.  When I try to convert the code I get the error that MSSTDFMT.dll(microsoft Data Formating object libary 1.0.0) is missing.  I doubt there is a Vb6 out there for me to install, any one have any idea's of how to convert this?

Comment: Could not load referenced components: 
msstdfmt.dll (Microsoft Data Formatting Object Library 1.0.0),
dbgrid32.ocx (1.0.0),
dblist32.ocx (1.1.0),
mci32.ocx (1.1.0),
msadodc.ocx (6.0.0),
mschrt20.ocx (2.0.0),
mscomm32.ocx (1.1.0),
MSDATGRD.OCX (1.0.0),
msdatlst.ocx (1.0.0),
msflxgrd.ocx (1.0.0),
mshflxgd.ocx (6.0.0),
msmask32.ocx (1.1.0),
msrdc20.ocx(2.0.0),
MSWINSCK.OCX(1.0.0),
picclp32.ocx(1.1.0),
sysinfo.ocx(1.0.0),
TABCTL32.OCX(1.1.0) 
It is recommended you install VB6.0, with all referenced components, 
and ensure the application compiles and runs before upgrading.</Issue>
</UpgradeLog>

Comment: What are you trying to "convert?"  If a VB6 program you shouldn't need this DLL for your new version, which shouldn't use it.  If not, then I don't understand the question at all.  VB6 is still available through MSDN Subscriptions though.

Comment: I don't have VB6 only the current 3.  the 2008 convert says it needs it for soe reason to convert the app to .net.  I don't think I can just drop all the frms and stuff into vs2012.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio's built in converter you will need Visual Basic 6 and the referenced libraries. There is some discussion of alternatives here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038447/vb6-migrating-to-net-with-visual-studio-2010

Comment: I will agree with that, but do I really need to purchase a copy of VB6 just to convert this and never use it again.

Comment: @StephanM To be able to run and debug the original code, yes. To just read it, you can use notepad or any other text editor.

Comment: Ok Thanks, Not Cool MS, but Ok

Answer (score 6):

I recently had a similar issue with one of my VB6 applications.

`MSSTDFMT.DLL` is not installed by default on Windows Vista/7/8. You will need to get a copy from another system, put it into the local system32 folder and apply regsvr to it.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708.aspx for a maxtrix of VB6 related files that are / are not installed with Vista/7/8.

Comment: Windows OS is never a delivery channel of the extended runtime files.